# Connection refused with Elixir/Phoenix using Postgres in Gitlab CI

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, elixir, gitlab-ci

While trying to build a test pipeline in Gitlab CI I faced a connection problem with the postgres service.

The output from the job execution is this:

```
$ mix ecto.setup
19:42:34.864 [error] GenServer #PID<0.345.0> terminating
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
** (Mix) The database for Gerard.Repo couldn't be created: killed
```

This is how my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like:

### **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
before_script:
  - mix local.rebar --force
  - mix local.hex --force
  - mix deps.get --only test
  - mix compile

test:
  stage: test
  image: elixir:1.7.4
  services:
    - redis:5.0.4
    - rabbitmq:3-management
    - localstack/localstack:latest
    - postgres
  variables:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_DB: gerard_test
    POSTGRES_HOST: localhost
    POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    MIX_ENV: "test"
  cache:
    paths:
      - _build
      - deps
  script:
    - mix ecto.setup
    - mix ecto.create
    - mix ecto.migrate
    - mix test
```

and this is how my `test.exs` file looks:

### **test.exs**

```
config :gerard, Gerard.Repo,
  username: System.get_env("GERARD_TEST_DB_USERNAME") || "postgres",
  password: System.get_env("GERARD_TEST_DB_PASSWORD") || "postgres",
  database: System.get_env("GERARD_TEST_DB") || "gerard_test",
  hostname: System.get_env("GERARD_TEST_DB_HOSTNAME") || "localhost",
  ownership_timeout: 900_000,
  timeout: 900_000,
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox
```

Also tried to change the POSTGRES_HOST to `db`, `127.0.0.1` and `postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres/gerard_test?` bot none of these worked

Comment: `POSTGRES_HOST: postgres`

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin It worked! But I also had to change my test.exs file so the hostname would look like this: if(System.get_env("CI"), do: "postgres", else: "localhost")

Answer (score 0):

Remove `POSTGRES_HOST=localhost` from `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Set `GERARD_TEST_DB_HOSTNAME=postgres`.

See: [GitLab Docs: Accessing the Services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services)